# Keras: Refeed an Output to the Input of a Defined Model

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I have a model in Keras whose structure is already fixed. This model got two inputs and one output. The output of the last step should be used to calculate the current output.
[sketch of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Cqg.jpg)

My approach looks like this:

```
model_1 = load_model(...)

x = Input(shape=(1,), name="input1")
input_concat = Concatenate([x, y])
y = model_1(input_concat)
```

I have already tried out, what **bstriner** at [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5160#issuecomment-358371839)  suggested for adding (I exchanged model_1 by a simple `Dense(1)`-Layer for reproducibility):

```
x = Input(shape=(1,), name="input1")
y = K.zeros(shape=(1,))
input_concat = Concatenate([x, y])
y = Dense(1)(input_concat)
```

.. but apparently the Concatenate doesn't work with the K.zeros(..) solution. (It also doesn't work with the `Add()`-Layer instead of the `Concatenate()`-Layer since after compiling the whole model by `model_total = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y` the following error appears

> `'Variable'` object has no attribute `'_keras_history'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the original Input-layer which is layer 0.

```
model_1 = load_model(...)
model_1.layers[0] = new_input_layer
```

However I'm still not sure if this will behave how you'd expect. You're going to turn a feed forward model into a recursive network. I expect you won't be able to train it.

Comment: Internally the model already has got the fitting input layer. I will update my drawing for a clarification